# Error: Expected a value of type 'FutureOr<Profile>', but got one of type '_JsonMap

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

This error is similar to another I've seen, but I'm not an experienced Flutter developer. I receive and print the *response.body* in the console. I change some code, and convert to <String, dynamic>, but then I get an error in my Provider, and when I try to write return ref.read(profileProvider) when I write the dot, the function of the API class does not appear.

I have this class below:

```html
class Profile {
  String status;
  String message;
  final Data data;
  Profile({
    required this.status,
    required this.message,
    required this.data,
  });

  factory Profile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Profile(
      status: json['status'],
      message: json['message'],
      data: Data.fromJson(json['data']),
    );
  }
}

class Data {
  String firstName;
  String middleName;
  String lastName;
  String email;
  String mobile;
  String picture;

  Data({
    required this.firstName,
    required this.middleName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.email,
    required this.mobile,
    required this.picture,
  });

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
      firstName: json['first_name'] ?? 'First Name Json',
      middleName: json['middle_name'] ?? 'Middle Name',
      lastName: json['last_name'] ?? 'Last Name',
      email: json['email'] ?? 'Your email',
      mobile: json['mobile'] ?? '999-999-9999',
      picture: json['picture'] ?? 'assets/profile-image-holder.png',
    );
  }
}
```

#### My API call

```html
class UserProfileService {
  Future<Profile> getProfileInfo() async {
    String? authToken = await readBearer();
    //debugPrint(authToken);
    final headers = {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": 'Bearer $authToken!',
    };
    try {
      final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(ApiConstants.baseUrl + ApiConstants.userProfileInfo),
        headers: headers,
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        //debugPrint((response.body));
        //final profileResponse = Profile.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
        final profileResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
        debugPrint(profileResponse.toString());
        return profileResponse;
      } else {
        return Profile.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle any exceptions that occur during the request
      return throw (Exception(error));
    }
  }
}
```

And finally, I'm using Riverpod in my Flutter project.

```html
final profileProvider =
    Provider<UserProfileService>((ref) => UserProfileService());
final profileDataProvider = FutureProvider<Profile>((ref) {
  return ref.read(profileProvider).getProfileInfo();
});
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting is completely off. It is definitely not HTML. What is it? [Dart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dart_%28programming_language%29)? Does it actually run (snippets are ***not*** for general formatting)?

Comment: Dart [is supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) for syntax highlighting, but presumably not for [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stack-snippets/info)(?).

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a `Profile` instance:

```dart
try {
    final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(ApiConstants.baseUrl + ApiConstants.userProfileInfo),
        headers: headers,
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return Profile.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    }
    else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load profile'); // Or custom
    }
} catch (error) {
    // Handle any exceptions that occur during the request
    return throw (Exception(error));
}
```

Try to convert it to an async method and await:

```dart
final profileDataProvider = FutureProvider<Profile>((ref) async {
    return await ref.read(profileProvider).getProfileInfo();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
After printing the response debugPrint(profileResponse.toString()); I get "Instance of 'Profile' ". This is were I was before getting this error, if you see the variable profileResponse commented three lines above the return in the Api call, and I do not know why. Maybe my class is not defined well, here is the dummy data I get from the response.

Comment: Dummy response below:.
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Listing user profile",
    "data": {
        "user_profile": {
            "first_name": "FirstName",
            "middle_name": "",
            "last_name": "Lastname",
            "email": "email@gmail.com",
            "picture": {
                "thumbnail": "/assets/user-image-holder.png",
                "big": "/assets/user-image-holder.png"
            },
            "url": "https://api.mypage.com/api/v1/user_profile"
        }
    }
}

Comment: For this response, it will be `return Profile.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)['data']['user_profile']);` you cast it to Map if needed.  You can also check[this example](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-project-Helper/blob/c963c504996a6c3e75b4ba6b0781d0aebae52b34/jsonFormating/sample1.dart#L50)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your time, I really appreciate it! I was able to get the data from the Api by passing the json to be generated automatically, I knew that there was something wrong with the class I built, but I cannot point out where the problem was. I used https://app.quicktype.io

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the data from the API by generating the class with https://app.quicktype.io. I knew there was something wrong with the class I manually made, but I can't tell where the error is.